# Distance Calculation Output Does Not Identify Input Points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, distance

I'm using ArcMap 10 to do distance calculations between a large set of points, using the point distance calculator.  The output table generated gives me distances correctly, but the output categories Near_FID and Input_FID are all the same

Here is what I'm doing:
I have a csv file with lat, long, FID, and a couple of other object identifiers.  I use "add data" in ArcMap, and pull in the csv.

From ArcToolbox I use "Make XY Event Layer" to generate a layer with all the observations or objects.  I then use the Point Distance calculator and set the new layer as both the "Input Features" and "Near Features."  It calculates distances for all points, correctly from what I can tell, but the "Input_FID" and "Near_FID" both take on the same single value repeated, and don't even match any of the FID numbers from the original layer.  As a result, I can't identify the paired points.

I am new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Just a note, make sure your shapefiles are projected as a Projected Coordinate System and not Geographic for measuring purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need to make the event layer from "Make XY Event Layer" permanent by exporting it to a shapefile or feature class before running the Point Distance tool against that.

The [Point Distance documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001r000000.htm) says that the input has to be Feature Layer but I would like to either see the tool prevent you inputting an Event Layer or to document explicitly that the tool does not support them.

Answer (score 2):

[PolyGeo appears to be right](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21560/115), at least as far as I can tell.  I was trying to calculate distances between points within a single XY layer.  I'm not sure if that's possible, but I ended up just breaking out the spreadsheets into two subsets.  I had one as a shapefile already, from which I generated an XY event layer.  The other subset was a csv file which I used ArcCatalog to generate a shapefile.  From there, using Point Distance worked flawlessly to generate distances between points in the xy layer and points in the shapefile.

From what I can tell that's how you're supposed to do it--I had a convoluted reason for doing it the other way, but this works out too.  Hopefully this helps someone who might have a similar question later.